# Display updated state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a to-do list in React. The items are stored in an object in the app's state. When the user checks the box, I can update the state, but not display the updated state. I know that changes to the state do not always immediately update the component, so I've tried passing the `render()` function as a callback to the `setState()` function, but I get an error saying `Invalid argument passed as callback. Expected a function. Instead received: [object Object]`. I've also tried adding the `componentDidUpdate()` function but didn't have any success using that method because I don't understand how it's triggered. How can I update the state then immediately display the updated state on the page?

So far what I have it this function which is triggered when a checkbox is checked/unchecked.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isLoading: null,
        isDeleting: null,
        list: null,
        title: "",
        term: "",
        content: []
    };
}

async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        const list = await this.getList();
        const { title, content } = list;

        this.setState({
            list,
            title,
            content
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}

checkedChange = async event => {
    let todos = Object.assign({}, this.state.content);
    let key = event.target.attributes[0].value;

    if(event.target.checked) {
        todos[key] = true;
        this.setState({todos});
    }
    else {
        todos[key] = false;
        this.setState({todos});
    }
};
```

Comment: You are fetching `this.state.content` and set the `todos`. Are you sure the DOM is bind with `todos`. And remove `this.render()` from `setState` it's redundant.

Comment: Why is `checkedChange` an async function? There is no reason I can see why it would be.

Comment: "changes to the state don't render right away" -- yes, they do.  Plz add the code where you set up your component's state.

Comment: @jered I don't know. That's what my IDE suggested. @front_end_dev I don't know what you mean by "the DOM is bind with `todos`".

Comment: @jmargolisvt I meant that setState "does not always immediately update the component." per the React documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `this.setState({todos})` is shorthand equivalent to writing `this.setState({todos: todos})`. So you are not updating `this.state.content` which I suspect is what you want to be doing. So try `this.setState({content: todos})`.

Edit: I highly recommend you install and use the [Chrome React developer tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en). It will show up in your dev tray as a tab next to Console, Inspector, etc. It is extremely useful for debugging and visualizing what's going on in your components.